# C function to enter a string

Tags: c, string, function

I am wondering why the below code acts as follows. The first time that I print the variable "account_name" it works correctly.  The second and third time, it does not work at all, but prints gibberish instead.  I am a beginner at C.

```
const char * get_account_name(){

    char loc_account_name[255];

    printf ("Please enter the ledger Account name: ");
    scanf ("%[^\n]", &loc_account_name);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf ("\n");
    return ( loc_account_name );
}

void main (void)
{

    /* Declare variables. We use the predefined "MAX_ENTRIES" definition to define how large the arrays will be */

    float   credits[MAX_ENTRIES], debits [MAX_ENTRIES], starting_balance, ending_balance;
    int     debit_amount, credit_amount, x;
    char    * account_name;

    printf ("Welcome to the Sears Ledger System\n\n");

    /* Prompt the user to enter the name of the account, we allow for up to 255 characters and account for names with spaces as well */ 
    account_name = get_account_name();
    printf("%s",account_name);
    printf("%s",account_name);
    printf("%s",account_name);


} /* end main*/
```

*** update

I have removed the ampersand in the get_account_name function's scanf.  I find then that it will print out the correct values more than once, however the program hangs forever after that.  Unfortunately my compiler I'm forced to use doesn't have a debugger, so i am still confused as to what is happening.

```
char * get_account_name(){

    char * loc_account_name;
    printf ("Please enter the ledger Account name: ");
    scanf ("%[^\n]", loc_account_name);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf ("\n");

    return loc_account_name;

}
```

******update 2

```
char *get_account_name() {

    char loc_account_name[255];
    char *r;

    printf ("Please enter the ledger Account name: ");
    scanf ("%[^\n]", &loc_account_name);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("%s\n", loc_account_name);

    *r = malloc(strlen(loc_account_name) + 1);
    strcpy(r, loc_account_name);
    return r;
}

void main (void)
{

    char     * account_name;

    /* Prompt the user to enter the name of the account, we allow for up to 255 characters and account for names with spaces as well */ 
    account_name = get_account_name();
    printf("%s\n", account_name);
    printf("%s\n", account_name);
    printf("%s\n", account_name);
    free(account_name);


} /* end main*/
```

Comment: `scanf ("%[^\n]", …)` Does this work?!

Comment: yes that has worked for me so far

Answer (score 4):

You are returning the address of a local variable `loc_account_name` from `get_account_name()`. This memory *does not exist* after the function returns. (Well, it looks like it still contains the same data for a short time, but not the second or third time you use it.)

To fix this, you can either:

- Allocate space (using `malloc()` or similar) for the string inside the `get_account_name()` function, and return a pointer to that space. The caller will be responsible for freeing the memory.

  ```
  char *get_account_name() {
      char loc_account_name[255];
      // get user input into loc_account_name
      char *r = malloc(strlen(loc_account_name) + 1);
      strcpy(r, loc_account_name);
      return r;
  }

  account_name = get_account_name();
  // use account_name
  free(account_name);
  ```

  Note that you can use `strdup()` instead of `malloc()`/`strcpy()` if your runtime library has one of those.
- Have the caller allocate some space for the maximum length of the string, and pass that buffer (and the buffer length) into the `get_account_name()` function for it to fill in.

  ```
  void get_account_name(char *buffer, int buffer_size) {
      // get user input into buffer
      // but make sure the user can't type more than buffer_size characters!
  }

  char account_name[255];
  get_account_name(account_name, sizeof(account_name));
  // use account_name
  ```

Returning strings from functions is awkward and annoying in C. This is why most modern languages (including C++) have better built-in ways to handle strings.

Comment: i have removed the ampersand so that it doesn't return the address of the local variable anymore.  I'm not sure if that is what was needed to fix it or not because although it now does in fact print out the correct string more than once, it hangs forever. (I have no debugging capabilities)  Would you be able to post a more detailed response using one of your methods, as I am unfamiliar with either.

Comment: Your updated code now reads the user text into some random place in memory pointed to by the uninitialised `loc_account_name` pointer. This is also wrong, as you've noticed. I'll add some code samples.

Comment: I have attempted your first solution above, but the results are very similar to when I removed the ampersand.  The system writes out the correct text 3 times in a row, and then crashes (mine simply hung instead of crashing, but not too dis-similar)  It appears to have something to do with the "free(" statement

Comment: Change your `*r =` to just `r =` without the asterisk. It sounds like you've still got some work to do on understanding pointers.

Comment: That did do the trick Greg, I do appreciate it.  And yes, your quite right I sure do have a long ways to go to understanding this.  I have been doing web programming for years and struggling now to try to understand C.  So far, randomly adding * and & has gotten me through even very high level programming courses when I was in school (sad but true), so I'm starting from scratch and trying to re-learn. So far still no more understanding though

Comment: It seems to me that we make a pointer to somewhere in memory to store "account_name".  The function get_account_name will return a pointer to a character as well.  Inside that function it has a local character array (not a pointer this time for some reason), and also a character pointer as well (not sure why we need both here!)  The scanf saves the input into the non-pointer version.  Then we take the pointer version (r) and give it just enough memory to accommodate the input, copy the input and return it.  This seems like a really strange way, and I would have never guessed it... :(

Comment: You've described the operation of the function pretty well with that. The key point to know is that the local array `loc_account_name` disappears when the function returns (just as it magically appeared when the function was entered). On the other hand, with `malloc` and `free` you can control when the memory appears and disappears, and free it after you're done using it, no matter when that happens.

Comment: The other key thing to remember is C does *not* stop you from trying to use memory that you're not supposed to use. Doing so gives you unpredictable consequences. :)

Answer (score 0):

In single-thread environments you can use simply a static buffer like:

```
const char *get_account_name(void) {

    static char loc_account_name[255];
    int c;

    printf ("Please enter the ledger Account name: ");
    scanf ("%254[^\n]", loc_account_name);
    while( (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n' );
    printf("%s\n", loc_account_name);

    return loc_account_name;
}
```

To clear the input-buffer you should **ever** use a standard-conforming way.